# OpenGL GL_BGR not working for texture internal format

Tags: opengl, colors, textures

From what I've read in the OpenGL documentation, OpenGL prefers BGR format over RGB. However, when setting the texture's internal format as BGR, the texture is all white when rendering. When the internal format is set to RGB or RGBA it displays properly. The source format is BGR to begin with (loaded directly from DIB).

```
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
 glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, nClamp);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, nClamp);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, nMagFilter);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, nMinFilter);
 glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

The following line is the problem... setting the internal format to GL_BGR makes everything all white... changing to GL_RGB makes it render correctly

```
 glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGR, pTex->nWidth, pTex->nHeight, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pTex->pBuffer);
```

Comment: What is `nMinFilter`?  If it has `MIPMAP` in it you're going to have to provide a complete set of mipmap levels.

Answer (score 3):

From the [glTexImage2D man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml), GL_BGR is not a internalFormat, just a format.

You should check for GL errors since that would've catched this error. What you read about "OpenGL prefering BGR" is false.